# How do I start a cron service on a web server programatically?

Tags: linux, apache, web, cron

I have been stuck on this for a while and this is new territory for me so I need some help. I am working on a project where a cron service is created when a user is created with a web application. However, I am running into problems actually getting the cron service to run. Here is what I have tried

1) Creating a cron service using

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "'comand'"; } | crontab -
```

This creates the job fine. However, it creates it with www-data as the user and those do not show to execute.

I should mention that I am setting path to

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

as I am running a python script that I have made executable using `chmod +x` and put the appropriate headers to make sure it runs properly (which it does). In addition, all paths are full paths. To be more clear, here is the actual command I am using inside the crontab

```
*/10 * * * * /home/user/path-to script/script.py --user_id 1 --db_file /home/user/path-to-file/file.db
```

However, the script never runs.

2) Creating a file under /etc/cron.d, but from my testing, I have realized that this only works if the file is created as a root user, which since the user creating the file is www-data, the job will again, not execute.

for reference, I am doing that as such:

```
*/10 * * * * user /home/user/path-to script/script.py --user_id 1 --db_file /home/user/path-to-file/file.db
```

What does work is repeating steps 2 & 3 using a user that is part of the sudo group or is the root user. This tells me that I need to create the cron job using one of those two users, but I am not sure how to do that programmatically when www-data is being used for web activities.

Another option I have considered is using `crontab -u user` to programmatically add the job to a user I know works, but the issue with that is that in order to do that I need sudo access and I don't want to pass in the sudo password when creating the cronjob or do something that might be potentially dangerous (like removing the need to use sudo as I know that is possible, but in my opinion could be very bad is someone gains access to the account and therefore has escalated privileges)

Help would really be appreciated.

As for the stack, if it's helpful, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64 and Apacahe2

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully grasped the use-case or the problem you're facing, but you can modify sudoers (create a dedicated file for that purpose, even)  that allows you to execute given commands w/o a password.  I, for instance, have a file `/etc/sudoers.d/vpn` containing `tink ALL = NOPASSWD:  /usr/local/bin/openfortivpn -c /etc/openfortivpn/my-config` that allows me to open a VPN connection w/o having to authenticate myself to `sudo` ...

Comment: @tink Thank you for the suggestion, but that is something I stated in my original post that I do not want to do to avoid compromising the safety of the system.

Comment: I don't see a great distinction if you permit the web-server process to modify crontab entries anyway ... if you pin it down to ONE thing the sudoer command grants you, and narrow that down well enough ...

Comment: You can you message queue-ing system, web application "sends" messages to create user's crontab entry and a daemon "reads" messages and creates crontab entries. A little bit simpler solution when web application write data to a file or named pipe, the daemon read that file or named pipe. Both of case you have to develop the daemon too. It is a little bit more complicated than @tink solution and naturally should also have security problems.